# Name of RF demodulation technique using a demultiplexer

Tags: rf, demodulation, sdr

I can't remember the name of a demodulation technique I read the whitepaper on.  My memory is not exact but I remember the following vaugely:

Core to it is a 1:4 demultiplexer run at 4x the desired frequency.  Each quarter wave is then filtered.  First and third quarter are combined to make I, second and fourth quarter are combined to make Q.  IQ demodulation continues as usual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tayloe detector, can be made with 1:2 demultiplexors or 1:4 demultiplexors in typical configurations, it does require an accurate quadrature clock.

Comment: Any more accurate than a zero-IF mixing approach?

Comment: @foreverska The Tayloe detector is *very often* used as a zero-IF mixer. Am unsure what you mean by *accuracy*? Dan Tayloe first described it in a zero-IF application, but it need not be limited to zero-IF mixing.

Comment: @glen_geek was just inquiring about the use of the word accurate in the answer.  Wasn't sure if it needed to be unusually accurate, if it was unusual for a quadrature clock to be  accurate or just a warning that the clock being quadrature was notable.

Comment: Jitter or asymmetry degrade receive performance.  If you are operating at low HF frequencies (<8mhz or so) it is not difficult to generate the clocks.  About 30Mhz you start having to watch for asymmetric rise/fall times on clock/drivers and differences in the turn-on/turn-off time of the mux.   At VHF (130-170Mhz) things get significant more tricky if you are implementing a direct to low or zero IF system.